# Calendário no perfil do usuário está quebrado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Quando clicamos no calendário que está no perfil, ele fica igual a imagem acima ai. Sei que no Firefox, IE, Edge e Chrome está assim.

---

Alguns usuários falaram que o calendário deles está mais louco ainda.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: No edge também.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto) It's now fixed and will be live after our next production build.

Comment: I want to accept this answer but i don't have the accept button ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Primeiro problema:

[image]

O calendário é na verdade se trata do jquery-ui, existem dois problemas, o primeiro é que por causa deste estilo:

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data th, .user-show-new .user-header .data td {
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Que está no arquivo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/br/all.css?v=1e6f41aabda2">
```

A cada letra adicionada é necessário aumentar a largura, pois existe `white-space: nowrap` que impede as quebras e o `padding: 3px 20px 3px 0;` que faz o que está a direita ter `20px`.

No caso os elementos `<th>` no site em inglês usam 2 letras pra cada dia da semana e no site em Português usa 3 letras.

**Vou ser sincero,** tenho algum conhecimento em CSS, e do meu ponto de vista é um **absurdo** usar `padding-left` e `padding-right` diretamente dentro de `<th>` e `<td>` (é apenas a minha opinião).

Não é o jQuery-ui que está afetando o layout, mas sim o `all.css`, pra corrigir o problema, basta editar este seletor em all.css:

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child th, .user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Para (eu testei e funcionou)

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child th, .user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

## Segundo problema:

[image]

Provavelmente foi algum erro ao carregar o documento CSS do jquery-ui ou outro estilo.

<s>#Terceiro problema (não mencionado)</s>

Nos outros sites da SE (como SOen) o site carrega apenas um jQuery-ui (ele é carregado automaticamente nos sites da SE), já no SOpt ele carrega duas vezes, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu disse ele é carregado/inserido dinamicamente (com javascript), pode ser que isto afete o layout dos elementos jquery-ui, pois existem regras do css ou comando do javascript que podem afetar o funcionamento (é teórico).

---

## First problem:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mPX6.png">
```

The calendar is actually it is `jquery-ui`, there are two problems, the first is that because of this style:

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data th, .user-show-new .user-header .data td {
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

## That is in the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/br/all.css?v=1e6f41aabda2">
```

Every added "character/letter" is necessary to increase the width because there `white-space: nowrap` that prevents the breaks and the `padding: 3px 3px 20px 0`, making the right of the element have `20px`.

If the elements `<th>` on the StackOverflow.com using two letters to each weekday and on the pt.stackoverflow.com uses 3 letters in `<th>`.

**I'll be honest**, I have some knowledge of CSS, and from my point of view is **nosense** to use `padding-left` and `padding-right` directly into `<th>` and `<td>`  (I hope that does not sound like offense, it is just my opinion).

It is not `jquery-ui` that is affecting the layout, but the `all.css` to fix edit this selector in `all.css`:

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child th, .user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

To (I tested it and it worked):

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child th, .user-show-new .user-header .data .days-visited tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

## Second problem:

[image]

It was probably some error loading the jquery-ui.css document (or other).

<s>#Third problem (not mentioned)</s>

In other sites of SE (eg. stackoverflow.com) the site carries only a `jquery-ui` (it is automatically loaded on the website of SE), as in `sopt` it loads twice, see:

[image: jquery-ui]

As I said it is loaded/inserted in document dynamically (with javascript), it may be that this affects the layout of `jquery-ui` elements because there are rules of css or javascript command that may affect operation (is theoretical).

Comment: Notou alguma falha na tradução, pode editar :)

Comment: Na verdade, o segundo problema foi constatado no Firefox do Jorge B. e do Ricardo. kkkk

Comment: @emanuelsn No meu Firefox (Windows) está normal, deve ter sido algum arquivo css ou outra coisa que não carregou.

Comment: Aqui o `jquery-ui.css` carrega só uma vez. Mas, excelente resposta!

Comment: Aqui continua igual o calendário. Começo a achar que o site não me curte :P

Comment: @Gabe Pode ter sido um BUG. Hoje não apresentou mais.

Comment: @JorgeB. Você disse que continua, seria o segundo? É Firefox com Ubuntu?

Comment: É sim Ubuntu com Firefox